# DB Connectivity: How to check it, depending on Network connectivity status

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, connectivity

I know how to programmatically get the connection status of the database.
What I am looking for is a way to check the status of the DB connection either after a WiFi switch on/off cycle, or a LAN cable plug/unplug.

Does someone have a clue on how to achieve such a check?

Answer (score 0):

You can check if network connection available by using:

```
System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable()
```

There is as well an event to check if the status is changed:

```
System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkChange.NetworkAvailabilityChanged
```